# laravel Controller method not found in route::controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using `Route::controller` to view and edit form. in this action laravel say :

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Controller method not found.
```

my Route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin' ,'before'=>'auth'), function(){

    Route::controller('profile', 'ProfileController', array('getIndex'=>'profile.index', 'postUpdate'=>'profile.update'));

});
```

my form:

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('route' => array('profile.update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

ProfileController:

```
class ProfileController extends \BaseController {

    public $layout = 'back_end.layouts.main';
    function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('getIndex', 'postUpdate')));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    }    
    public function getIndex()
    {
        if( Auth::check() ){
           $profiles = Auth::user();
          return  View::make('back_end.layouts.profile')->with('profile', $profiles);
        }
        else return Redirect::intended('login');
    }

    public function postUpdate($id)
    {
       if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
       {
            return Response::view('back_end.missing', array(), 404);
       }

       $rules = array(
            'name'        => 'required|alpha',
            'family'      => 'required',
            'email'       => 'required|email',
            'currPassword'=> 'required',
            'password'    => 'required|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'required',
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
           return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        }
        $id   = Input::get ('id');
        $data = User ::find($id);
        $HashPassowrd = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        if( ! Hash::check( Input::get('currPassword') , $data->password ) )
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
            ->withErrors('Current Password Error!');
        }
        else{

            $admin = new User;
            $admin = User::find($id);
            $admin->name     = Input::get('name');
            $admin->family   = Input::get('family');
            $admin->email    = Input::get('email');
            $admin->password = $HashPassowrd;
            $admin->save();

            return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
            ->withErrors('Edit Successfull');
        }
    }
}
```

**php artisan route**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                                    | Name                | Action                                | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /                                                                  |                     | Closure                               |                |               |
|        | GET index                                                              | index               | Closure                               |                |               |
|        | GET admin/index                                                        | dashboard           | Closure                               |                |               |
|        | GET logout                                                             | logout              | Closure                               |                |               |
|        | POST auth                                                              | auth                | Closure                               | csrf           |               |
|        | GET login                                                              | login               | Closure                               |                |               |
|        | GET admin/profile/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}         | profile.index       | ProfileController@getIndex            | auth           |               |
|        | GET admin/profile                                                      |                     | ProfileController@getIndex            | auth           |               |
|        | POST admin/profile/update/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       | profile.update      | ProfileController@postUpdate          | auth           |               |
|        | GET admin/profile/{_missing}                                           |                     | ProfileController@missingMethod       | auth           |               |
|        | GET admin/manaheHeaders/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   | manageHeader.index  | ManageHeadersController@getIndex      | auth           |               |
|        | GET admin/manaheHeaders                                                |                     | ManageHeadersController@getIndex      | auth           |               |
|        | POST admin/manaheHeaders/update/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} | manageHeader.update | ManageHeadersController@postUpdate    | auth           |               |
|        | GET admin/manaheHeaders/{_missing}                                     |                     | ManageHeadersController@missingMethod | auth           |               |
|        | GET test                                                               | test                | Closure                               |                |               |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Maybe check the output of `artisan routes` to ensure your URIs and route names are correct. Also you didn't mention (or I didn't see) exactly where the error comes up - is it during the call to `Form::open()`, or if you go to the URI in your browser (or both)? If the `Form::open()` call is fine and displaying the form, it may be worth checking the URL it is generating to make sure that matches your expectation from your routes.

Comment: What is the URL you are hitting?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro in route or controller?

Comment: URL = `http://box.dev/what/url/are/you/hitting`?

Comment: Is this happening when you send the form or when Laravel is trying to render the form? By other comments, looks like the form is rendering, at least you have an URL... Just want to be sure if it's happening when you click a button to post the form...

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
 v---- (POST)
POST admin/profile/update/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       | profile.update      | ProfileController@postUpdate          | auth           |               |
```

But in the form you have used `'method' => 'PUT'` (in the `Form::model()`) so `HTTP` method doesn't match and hence the method is not there because you have `postUpdate`.

> The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI
>   the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the
>   controller. Next, just add methods to your controller, **prefixed with
>   the HTTP verb they respond to**:

So, the method should be prefixed with `put` or change the request method `POST` which is set by default so you may remove the method from the form if you intend to use `POST`, IMO.

Comment: change `PUT` to `POST` or remove `method` from `Form` not resolve this problem

Comment: Are you sure about this, did you try ?

Comment: yes. check this link http://paste.debian.net/82247/ i get this error now: `Controller method not found.`

Comment: What `url` is generated in the `Form::model` as `action` ?